# Why angular function needs to be nested?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started to learn AngularJS and I saw a tutorial that gives the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{x | myFormat}}
</li>
</ul>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
        var i, c, txt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            c = x[i];
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                c = c.toUpperCase();
            }
            txt += c;
        }
        return txt;
    };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
        ];
});
</script>

<p>Make your own filters.</p>
<p>This filter, called "myFormat", will uppercase every other character.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I was wondering - why the function needs to be nested? Why I can't write this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFormat', function(x) {
        var i, c, txt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            c = x[i];
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                c = c.toUpperCase();
            }
            txt += c;
        }
        return txt;
});
```

And another question - where\who passed the x to the function? I know that most of the time I passed data to finction like this - `foo(x,y)` - where is here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is by Design. `filter` API has function which return `function`(filtering logic).  Basically the outer can be utilized to take use of angular dependency. And the inner returned function gets evaluated on each digest cycle.

```
//sample filter
app.filter('upperCase',[ '$window', function($window){ //you could have dependency here
   //inner function
   return function(x){
      return x.toUpperCase();
   }
}]);
```

In above `x` is the value on which filter gets applied. In your case `{{x | myFormat}}` that parameter will be `x` variable scope value. Whenever you wanted to pass multiple parameters in filter you could pass more value by mentioning right after your filter name separated by `:`

```
{{x | myFormat: y: z}}
```